# Launching the calendar on the week view on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

AppointmentManager.ShowTimeFrameAsync is showing the day view on Windows Phone no matter what duration I specify. I want to be able to launch the calendar on the week view.

Link to the API reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.appointments.appointmentmanager.showtimeframeasync

Answer (score 0):

Day is the default view of calender app. currently Appointment API does not provide any method/Property to change/set default view of calender. User has to do change the view in calender app to see weekly view

Comment: Thank you for your comment but using 
`await AppointmentManager.ShowTimeFrameAsync(DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeSpan.FromDays(7));` 
in Windows 8.1 opens the calendar on the week view while it does not work on Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a5d74c67-4db0-47a2-a503-df9b421d6799/can-not-launch-calendar-to-the-week-view-on-wp81?forum=wpdevelop) there is no way at the moment to launch the calendar on the week view.

Note: I have submitted a request to fix problem in the next release.